# Android Studio Java - How do I add more than one text on a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, button

Is there a way to add text in this specific layout instead of constantly pressing the space button and trying to align the number with the previous buttons.
[image: 1]

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn1"
        **android:text="1                  Item                                  number"**
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.44"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn1"
        **android:text="2                    Item                         number"**
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.177" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use a `Button`. Use a `ConstraintLayout` with suitable rules for the three pieces of text, mark that it is clickable and focusable, and give it a `StateListDrawable` background that renders as you want for click events.

Answer (score 0):

This way is not a good practice to fulfill your requirement as android xml have some rules for managing the views and it's content over the screen.

You can use `ConstraintLayout` functionality for managing views in chains like a horizontal management in your case or vertical management. You can visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-chain) to understand the basic and try to work around on it to be the master. You can use the weights with chain showing inside the image to meet your requirement.

[image]

There is another option available when using `LinearLayout` which provides the **weight** to show the views over the screen you can create horizontal oriented linear layout and provide the three views either button or text as you wanted and then provide the weight for them as per your requirement.